# NoReverseMatch thrown in class based view

Tags: django

So I have a view that lists a bunch of links:

```
class CheckpointSelectView(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model               = Checkpoint
    template_name       = 'warden/checkpoint_select_view.html'
    context_object_name = 'checkpoints'
```

A template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for checkpoint in checkpoints %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'checkpoint' checkpoint_name=checkpoint.name %}">{{ checkpoint.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And some urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', CheckpointSelectView.as_view(), name='checkpoint_selection'),
    url(r'^(?P<checkpoint_name>\w+-{0,1}\w+)/$', CheckpointWatchView.as_view(), name='checkpoint'),
]
```

Django throws a NoReverseMatch exception when I navigate to that view, but if I change the template like so:

```
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for checkpoint in checkpoints %}
            <li><a href="{{ checkpoint.name }}">{{ checkpoint.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

it works.

Am I using the url tag wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Traceback:

```
NoReverseMatch at /en/warden/

Reverse for 'checkpoint' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'checkpoint_name': 'start'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(ro|en)/warden/(?P<checkpoint_name>\\w+-{0,1}\\w+)/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/warden/
Django Version:     1.10.7
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'checkpoint' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'checkpoint_name': 'start'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(ro|en)/warden/(?P<checkpoint_name>\\w+-{0,1}\\w+)/$']

Exception Location:     /home/jotun/workspace/.virtualenvs/AESH/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  /home/jotun/workspace/.virtualenvs/AESH/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.2
```

Comment: Please show the full exception.

Comment: right, forgot about that, edited

Comment: So you've got a language parameter at the start of your pattern, with two options. How can `reverse` know which one to use? You should make that a capturing parameter (like `checkpoint_name`) and pass it in.

Comment: that did the trick, I was ignoring that since it was coming from another urls.py, thanks!!